# MySql Load data infile fields separated by cama splitting singe column data in to two fields due to cama presents in data

Tags: mysql, csv, import, load, load-data-infile

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' spliting my csv file single column data into two fields.

Here is my code:

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'E:/conversion/assets as on 29-10-2015.csv' INTO TABLE `tmx_ind_asset_stg_tb` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES(`id`,`make`,`model`,`desc`,`sn`,`customer`)

desc column data in csv is : TESTERS, VENTILATOR

but loading data as two fields in database TESTERS in to `desc` and VENTILATOR in to `sn` field.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate such fields by a chosen character (" is the most widly used character):
"TESTERS, VENTILATOR"

and use

```
    [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
    [ESCAPED BY 'char']
```

parameters of the load data command.

Comment: Thank you, But I have 19000 unique descreptions how can i do that

Comment: I have 19000 defferant descriptions How to mention in  'char'  in [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
[ESCAPED BY 'char']  if any thing wrong in my question excuse me, I am not well experienced

Comment: I'm afraid, I do not understand your question. If your data is enclosed by a character and you specify that character in load data, then data within the enclosure will be interpreted as a single data item.